# How do I use localstorage now? Is it not supported yet?

Tags: amp-html

In AMPHTML,i want to write a function to view recent records, but I don't want to use cookies.

Comment: Local storage is not available in AMPHTML.

Comment: Can I only use cookie to solve this problem?

Comment: No, if you need persistence across sessions, I think you would need backend support, with amp-list, for example.

Answer (score 0):

By "write a function", I am assuming you meant in the context of an AMP extension as currently amp-script.is still in development and custom JavaScript isn't allowed. If so, then there is nothing preventing you from creating a custom amp component to achieve what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know since when AMP started supporting amp-scripts or localStorage, but nowadays it is possible to use them.

They have an example in their site: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-script/#local-storage

> Your script has access to the Web Storage API. This lets you persist user information between browser sessions. Here, we use localStorage to track a username. If you set the username, then reload this page, the username will remain set.

```html
<amp-script layout="fixed-height" script="local-storage-script" height="110" class="sample">
  <div>
    <span>Current username: </span>
    <b id="username-display"></b>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Enter new username:</label>
    <input id="username-input" type="text" maxlength="20">
  </div>
  <button id="username-submit">Submit</button>
</amp-script>
<script id="local-storage-script" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
  const submit = document.getElementById('username-submit');
  const input = document.getElementById('username-input');
  const display = document.getElementById('username-display');

  const oldUsername = localStorage.getItem('username');
  display.textContent = oldUsername ? oldUsername : '(not set)';

  function setUsername() {
    const newUsername = input.value;
    localStorage.setItem('username', newUsername);
    display.textContent = newUsername;
  }

  submit.addEventListener('click', setUsername);
</script>
```